# Shiny name of multiple sliders

Tags: r, shiny

I have a big and complex code.

I have created a  uiOutput("sliders") in the ui in order to have some sliders (depending on the number of columns of a dataset I am able to upload).
In the server I have the following code:

```
output$sliders <- renderUI({
    pvars <- file_col()/2-1
    myList<-list()
    lapply(seq(pvars), function(i) {
    
        sliderInput(inputId = paste0("Shiftindex", i),label = ("Shift index")
                    ,min = 0, max = 1,value= 0,step = 0.1)
    }
    )

  })
```

I want to use the value of each sliderInput again in the server in order to compute something else.
My question is how I can put names in the sliders in order to be able to use their values in the server again and how I have to call them??

Comment: You can access their values on the server side with `input[[paste0("Shiftindex", 1)]]` for example. You could do something like the following: 
```r
output$text <- renderText({
  pvars <- file_col()/2-1
  slider_inputs <- paste0("Shiftindex", seq(pvars))
  values <- purrr::map_dbl(slider_inputs, function(x) input[[x]])
  paste(values, collapse = ", ")
})
```

Just let me know if you need extra help :)

Comment: @TomasCapretto, please post your comment as answer as it might help others looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can access their values on the server side with  `input[[paste0("Shiftindex", 1)]]` for example.

You could do something like the following:

```r
output$text <- renderText({
  pvars <- file_col()/2-1   
  slider_inputs <- paste0("Shiftindex", seq(pvars))   
  values <- purrr::map_dbl(slider_inputs, function(x) input[[x]])   
  paste(values, collapse = ", ") 
})
```

Just let me know if you need extra help :)

Comment: Thank you so much. My problem is also that I want to use the values of each slider in server. data1 <- reactive({for (i in 1:(ncol(data())/2-1)){ d$t[[i]] <-d$t[[i]] + output.text (here I want the value selected from each slider) return(d)}. Any idea??

Comment: I just showed how to use within text, but you can use them within a calculation or something you want. Could you give me more information about what you are trying to do?

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself well. I have a uiOutput with a renderUi in the server.

Comment: This renderUI is making many sliders (depending on the columns of the file uploaded). So, I want to take these values and compute a new number (the new number is the previous plus the value of the slider).